# Meraki guided access not working on iPAD

Tags: guided-access

I am trying for for Single App mode for one of my App using "Meraki" MDM, registered the device on the MDM site and created the profile.

I am using below code as suggested in this site, the code works fine on simulator but not on iPad."UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession" is not fired. Can someone help me what I am missing here.

```
NSLog(@"requesting guided access");
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(YES, ^(BOOL didSucceed) {
    if (didSucceed) {
        NSLog(@"entered guided access");
        self.inGuidedSessionMode = YES;
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"entered single access mode" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"failed to enter guided access");
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unable to enter single access mode" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the device is [supervised](https://documentation.meraki.com/SM/Profiles_and_Settings/iOS_supervised_restrictions_(e.g%2C_iMessage%2C_Game_Center%2C_App_removal)_do_not_apply), which is done through Apple Configurator or the Apple Device Enrollment Program.